# Serial Subsetting in R

Tags: r, subset

I am working with a large datasets. I have to extract values from one datasets, the identifiers for the values are stored in another dataset. So basically I am subsetting twice for each value of one category. For multiple category, I have to combine such double-subsetted values. So I am doing something similar to this shown below, but I think there must be a better way to do it.

example datasets

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(number= seq(5020, 5035, 1), value =rnorm(16, 20, 5),
        type = rep(c("food", "bar", "sleep", "gym"), each = 4))

df2 <- data.frame(number= seq(5020, 5035, 1), type = rep(LETTERS[1:4], 4))
```

extract value for grade A

```
asub_df2 <-subset(df2, type == "A" )
asub_df <-subset(df, number == asub_df2$number)
new_a <- cbind(asub_df, grade = rep(c("A"),nrow(asub_df)))
```

similarly extract value for grade B in `new_b` and combine to do any analysis.

can we use

Comment: hi akrun, i have not had much practice of `lapply` etc. could u elaborate how i can use it?

Comment: Perhaps `lapply(split(df2, df2$type), function(x) transform(subset(df, number==x$number), grade= x$type[1]))`

Comment: `df2 <- data.frame(number= seq(5020, 5035, 1),  type = rep(LETTERS[1:4], 4))` is that what u asking me to show?

Comment: that works great. Thank You.. let me try that in my original datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `split` the 'df2' and use `lapply`

```
Filter(Negate(is.null),
   lapply(split(df2, df2$type), function(x) {
        x1 <- subset(df, number==x$number)
          if(nrow(x1)>0) {
           transform(x1, grade=x$type[1])
             }
          }))
```